# select count always giving while a condition exists

Tags: oracle

I have the below block

```
declare TABLE_NAME varchar(200);
ALTCOUNT number(2);
TABLE_NAME ='TEST';
begin
ALTCOUNT :=0;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO ALTCOUNT FROM A_TABLES A WHERE A.TABLE_NAME = ''||UPPER(TABLE_NAME)||'';
IF ALTCOUNT =0 THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('insert into A_TABLES (TABLE_NAME ,A_TABLE_NAME) values('a','w');
end;
```

my problem is in this query

> SELECT COUNT(1) INTO ALTCOUNT FROM A_TABLES A WHERE A.TABLE_NAME = ''||UPPER(TABLE_NAME)||'';

even if `a.table name ='TEST and table_name ='TEST'` the count(1) is always = 0 . 
 Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're querying for a table called `'TEST'`, *including* the quotes. At least I think you are, though what you've shown won't run. You don't need to quote the variable. But you've created a scoping problem by giving the variable the same name as the table column, so use something else - a prefix is often used for this:

```
declare
  l_table_name varchar2(200);
  l_count number(2);
begin
  l_table_name := 'TEST';

  select count(1) into l_count
  from a_tables a
  where a.table_name = l_table_name;

  if l_count = 0 then
    insert into a_tables (table_name, a_table_name) values ('a','w');
  end if;
end;
/
```

You had several other problems that would have prevented this running at all as shown, so I guess it wasn't your actual code. You also don't need the dynamic SQL so I've removed that.

Comment: the problem was with the table name ... but why it was confused ? I added alias A to specify that its related to the table

Comment: If you said `where a.table_name = table_name`, you've specified that the first `table_name` is from the table with the alias (though it's redundant); but the scoping rules mean will still look at the table column first for the second `table_name` too. Not having an alias doesn't mean it *won't* use the table column. In a stored procedure you can use the procedure name in place of the alias, but in an anonymous block you don't have the option, so you need a different name for the variable to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
WHERE A.TABLE_NAME = ''||UPPER(TABLE_NAME)||''
```

to

```
WHERE A.TABLE_NAME = UPPER(table_name)
```

And in the newer versions, **COUNT(1)** is same as **COUNT(*)**.